# Microsoft.Extensions.* 3.1.* is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 on Azure agent "windows-latest"

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-pipelines, msbuild-task, build-agent

NuGet restore failed to restore packages on build pipeline (windows-latest). Had to pin the build agent to windows-2019 to get it working again.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 3.1.21 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 3.1.21 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 3.1.21 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 3.1.21 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.

Comment: The question is, why is this an issue? This should not be an error.

Comment: The issue seems only to be related to Build Pipeline Task NuGetCommand@2: restore.

Comment: Do you have an explicit UseDotNet task in your workflow to set the version to build against?

Comment: Have you tried the `Dotnet` task with the restore command?

Comment: This morning it worked and now not anymore, so this must be a new issue.

Comment: It's possible the rollout of the changeover from windows-2019 to windows-2022 for the windows-latest label went live on your account yesterday.

Comment: This changes the default versions of visual studio, MSBuild, dotnet core, x86 to x64 and a few other things that can cause this issue.